# Custom component's parent is null

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, parent, custom-component

I have created a custom panel component `XXPanelGroup` which extends `HtmlPanelGroup`, just to add the `XXComponentHandler` to the tag. The tag is placed inside a composite component. Inside this custom panel component I have another custom tag, with its own `YYComponentHandler`. In this handler I need the full path of the parent component which is my `XXPanelGroup`.

But, unexpectedly, the parent component is `null`. When I tried to call `setParent()` explicitly, I got the following exception:

```
Parent was not null, but this component not related
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.eraseParent(UIComponentBase.java:517)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.access$400(UIComponentBase.java:99)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2629)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBaseChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2603)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.addComponent(ComponentSupport.java:559)
    ...
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to insert the component in the component tree:

```
public class SomeHandler extends ComponentHandler {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onComponentCreated(FaceletContext context, UIComponent component, UIComponent parent) {
        parent.getChildren().add(component);
    }
}
```